# how run multiple servers locally using shell script?

Tags: macos, shell

I have to run three servers (s1,s2,s3) locally. Currently I am doing it manually by running them on 3 different terminal windows. The one catch here is that these servers needs to be run one by one in order first s1, then s2 and then s3. I was thinking of writing a shell script to perform this, but I am little new to shell scripting. Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: will this help `./start-server-1.sh && ./start-server-2.sh && ./start-server-3.sh`

Comment: thanks for response. But will this make s2 get started when s1 server is up ... also s3 get started when s2 server is up ?

Comment: Nope, it will trigger all one by one like server-1 will start first then 2nd and then 3rd. It does not check whether server-1 start is successful or not, it works only  if response code of last command executed by script `server-1.sh` is 0, else it will fail,  e.g. `pwd && ll && cd ~/Desktop` and `cd --- && ll && cd ~/Desktop`